"typedefing" base class in templates
While doing some simple metaprogramming, I encountered the following annoying syntax issue.
I need to derive some templated class from another templated class with a rather non-trivial and long list of template parameters. I also have to address an inner type that has been defined in the base class from inside the derived class definition.
In distilled form, it looks something like this:
template<int X, int Y, int Z>
class A : public B<X-1,Y-1,Z-1>
{
  typedef B<X-1,Y-1,Z-1>::SomeType MyType;
};

The long base class definition (B<X-1,Y-1,Z-1>) is typed more than once. In usual case, I typedef such class and use its simple "typedef-ed" alias. However, in case of inheritance, there's no place to do it before the inheritance statement, and one must use it at least once in its full form, which kind of defies the typedef purpose.
Is there any syntax trick that can allow me to typedef the base class only once? The default template parameter will not work for a template pack and for template specifications in general, I think.
UPD: typedefing the inherited templated base class with base ctors call

Can you post a [mre]? What is now shown has a lot of issues. B is undefined. Missing typename prior to dependent type name.

Is usage of macros an option?

I guess less preferable

typedef B<X-1, Y-1, Z-1> MyBase;  typedef MyBase::SomeType MyType; will help (instead of typing B<X-1, Y-1, Z-1>, type MyBase which will be less error prone).   Probably preferable (assuming a sufficiently recent C++ standard) to use using though.  e.g.  using MyBase = B<X-1, Y-1, Z-1>; using MyType = MyBase::MyType;

You can make it like
template <int X, int Y, int Z>
struct B {
  typedef int SomeType;
};

template <int X, int Y, int Z, typename B = B<X - 1, Y - 1, Z - 1>>
class A : public B {
  using MyType = typename B::SomeType;
  typedef typename B::SomeType MyType2;
};

int main() { A<1, 2, 3> a; }

With the hidden 4th template parameter
namespace detail {

template <int X, int Y, int Z, typename B = B<X - 1, Y - 1, Z - 1>>
class A : public B {
  using MyType = typename B::SomeType;
  typedef typename B::SomeType MyType2;
};

}  // namespace detail

template <int X, int Y, int Z>
using A = detail::A<X, Y, Z>;

Or
namespace detail {

template <typename B>
class A : public B {
  using MyType = typename B::SomeType;
  typedef typename B::SomeType MyType2;
};

}  // namespace detail

template <int X, int Y, int Z>
using A = detail::A<B<X - 1, Y - 1, Z - 1>>;


Thanks!!! That might do the trick for primary definition. But what if one of the parameters in primary template is pack and you are writing specialized template see example here https://godbolt.org/z/r1dKj39MG. I cannot wrap my head round it.

In this case the other shown options are applicable.

Do you think you can publish reworked https://godbolt.org/z/r1dKj39MG example for your second option?

his is a completely different question about overloaded/specialized class templates. Please post a new question.

Another way to avoid repeating the template parameter list in your typedef is to use the fact that a class name is injected in the class scope:
template <int X, int Y, int Z>
struct B {
  using SomeType = int;  
};

template <int X, int Y, int Z>
class A : public B<X - 1, Y - 1, Z - 1>
{    
    using MyType = A::B::SomeType;
};

int main() { A<1, 2, 3> a; }

The way it works: B (without parameters) is injected in B<X - 1, Y - 1, Z - 1>. It is inherited by A, but to make it available in A, you must make it a dependent name. Since A is also injected in A<X,Y,Z>, the easiest way to make B dependent is  A::B::SomeType.

Your example from godbolt.org/z/r1dKj39MG is even easier. You had
template<int Index, typename ... Rest>
struct Sequence
{
    static const int Size = Index;
};

template<int Index, typename F, typename ... Rest /*, typename X = Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>*/> 
struct Sequence<Index, F, Rest ...> : public Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>
{
    const int MySize = Sequence<Index+1, Rest ...>::Size; // just for fun no meaning
};

You can simply omit the template arguments and write:
const int MySize = Sequence::Size;

This is because Size is already inherited by the most derived struct Sequence, and all you need is to make it dependent.

didn't notice that you can shorten the type and not have any arguments. I reworked the example https://godbolt.org/z/YTMhnqG1z. Sequence in this case is not the same as the base class as witnessed by is_eq. But I guess it finds it because of inheritance

constexpr is the proper choice for second snippet. const is a pre-C++11 practice.
